# pass data from activity to fragment multiple times

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a 2X2 nested arraylist with data in an activity. A fragment uses one row of the arraylist data at a time and does some process. After the process, next row of data is required. I do not want to send more data to the fragment than it requires. Hence, I need to pass data multiple times to the fragment. What is the best way to achieve this?

NOTE: I tried using bundle, but it cannot be reused. I get an error "Fragment is Active."

Comment: Callback or event bus.

Comment: can you provide me a link on how to make a callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the approach described on the Android Developer Training website, here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

If you want to send data from Activity to a Fragment, you can get the fragment from the fragment manager by using a TAG (that you provide when adding / replacing the fragment). When you get the fragment, you can call it's public method to pass the data.

**Starting the fragment with a TAG**

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new MyFragment(), "MyFragmentTag");
```

**Getting the fragment within Activity using the TAG**

```
MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) manager.findFragmentByTag("MyFragmentTag");
if (fragment != null)
{
    fragment.passData(myData);
}
```

** `passData` is a public function within fragment `MyFragment`.

Comment: myData is returning null in the fragment while it has a value in the activity. I am not able to understand why is the value not being passed.

Comment: Can you explain how are you using it, what is the workflow?

Comment: I had defined say Frag_A = a; a = new Frag_A() .Then I would add the fragment and then send data as a.send(data1). After the process I would destroy the fragment. To send new data, I would add the fragment again and do a.send(data2). But the variable a is still assigned to the past fragment. So I had to reassign a = new Frag_A(); and then do a.send(data2). This worked.

Comment: Glad to hear, you got it working! If my answer helped you, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to make it.

There will be two receivers,one in activity as receiver1,and the other in fragment as receiver2,when you want to send data from activity,send broadcast with data then receiver2 can receive it.if you want more data from activity,send broadcast then receiver1 can receive it and send more data.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best option for you will be to add some public method to the fragment, and then access it from the activity.

More or less it should look like this:

Activity:

```
fragment = new YourFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
getFragmentTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();

///// somewhere else in the activity
fragment.setNewDataRow(newData);
```

Fragment:

```
public void setNewDataRow(DataRow dataRow) {
    // do what you need to do and update view etc.
}
```

That should be what you need :)